# How to only show map of items if they exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I am trying to repeat over an object to show some stuff on my app with react, this works fine if I have items in the object already, but at first (before I call the server) the object is empty and thus undefined so it breaks the component. I'm wondering what the best way to work with this is. I am using `immutable.js` and `redux` behind my react. I tried something like this in the render of the component:

```
   render: function(){
    var filterRepeat;
    if (this.props.filters){
        filterRepeat =  { this.props.filters.map(function(filterGroup){
                if (filterGroup.filters.length > 0){
                    return <myFilterCOmponent filterGroup={filterGroup} />
                }
            })
            };
    }
```

And then I just drop in `{filterRepeat}`, however it does not seem to like this syntax. I know you can do it like that for normal html but it seems like it's different for the maps evaluate.

I also tried setting it by default in the reducer to see if I could just have a default value set in there with immutable like this :

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

var presetState = Map();
presetState.set('filters', {});

export default function reducers(state = presetState, action) {
```

This does not seem to work either. So I am wondering with that best approach is for something like this with react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Just [set default props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops) so that it always exists:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      filters: []
    };
  }
  render: function() {
    var filterRepeat = this.props.filters.map(function(filterGroup, i){
      return (
        <MyFilterComponent key={i} filterGroup={filterGroup} />
      );
    });

    <div>{filterRepeat}</div>
  }
});
```

I also added a `key` prop to each `MyFilterComponent`. [Read why this is important here.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

Answer (score 0):

Add "else return null;" at the first if of your first option. Set to an array on your second option.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to ensure that your parent component always passes in a valid `props.filters` (empty array in the base case). Then your child component can blindly iterate over `this.props.filters` and render your `<myFilterCOmponent />`.

Also look into using react [React propTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) to ensure that a prop for your component is required, isArray etc.